# ArrayList not printing all elements

Tags: java, arraylist

I writing a program that takes a string inputted by user. (example: 175-24-56-5)
The program takes that string and puts it in an ArrayList. The problem I'm having is that when I try to print the ArrayList, the last number (that should be in the ArrayList) isn't printed.

Here's my  code for that method:

```
    public void dc(String txt) {
    ArrayList<String> unkey = new ArrayList<String>();
    int l = txt.length();
    int x = 0;
    String xx = "";
    String k = "";
    for (int j = l; j > 0; j--) {
        xx = Character.toString(txt.charAt(x));
        System.out.println(xx);
        if (xx.equals("-")) {
            unkey.add(k);
            k = "";
        } else {
            k += xx;
        }
        x++;
    }
    System.out.println(l);
    System.out.println(unkey);
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

It should have printed

```
{175, 24, 56, 5}
```

But it only prints

```
{175, 24, 56}
```

I'm relatively new to this. Any help? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Thanks, guys! @DontRelaX had the simplest answer for me! :) and it worked.. All I had to do was add `unkey.add(k)` after the for loop :) thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
unkey.add(k);
```

after cycle. You add numbers only when you found '-' now.

Comment: Thanks! It worked.. Seems so intuitive, I don't know why I didn't think of that

Answer (score 2):

Your issues is with for loop condition where you are missing 0th element. So your for-loop condition should be `>= 0` and start with l-1

Instead of parsing string character by character, you could use the following:

```
String[] numbers = txt.split("-");//Using List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(number); you can convert to list.
for (int i =0; i< numbers.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(numbers[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start at l-1 and end >=0. Strings run from index 0 to length-1

Answer (score 0):

The array starts with index 0 so your for loop needs to be:

for (int j = l; j >= 0; j--) {

Though you could simplify this whole thing by using "split":

```
String[] nums = txt.split("-");

ArrayList<String> unkey = Arrays.asList(nums);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `>` to `>=` so you're not leaving out the 1st element:

```
for (int j = l; j >= 0; j--)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that. If I do that, I get an error. `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 22`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int j = l; j > 0; j--)
```

this line should be changed to

```
for(int j=l-1; j>=0; j--)
```

For your specific example (175-24-56-5) are stored in the index order of (0-1-2-3) not (1-2-3-4).

Hope it helps